# Java/Replacing elements in a simple array with a while loop

Tags: java, arrays

I have two Arrays (not ArrayLists):

```
A: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
B: [50, 100, 150, 200, 250];
```

I need to create a while loop that inserts the values from array B to array A.
For example, If position/index K = 5, then the result should be:

```
A: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 30, 35, 40, 45];
```

Such that the contents of B[] get inserted in-place into A[], at index `K`. This pushes existing contents to the right, and deletes any content that is pushed outside the bounds of the array.

Then I need to use a `do while` loop to print out the new A values.

I need to do all that using 2 loops: 1 `while loop` for replacing and a `do While` loop for printing. Even if that is not necessary, those are the conditions given to me.

**In the context of my question, all that is mentioned in the assignment is:
Nest all the elements of Array B in the Array A according to the element with an index K.**

Sorry if I am being unclear, I began learning programming 5 days ago and I am not that familiar as to what details I should mention, maybe the code that I have wrote up until now can help to bring some more context (The first while loop is where I try to do what I am asking in this thread):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rainers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int A[] = new int[15];
        int B[] = new int[5];
        for (int i = 10; i < A.length; i++) {
            A[i] = 0;
        }
        int K;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Name Lastname ID1 ID2");
        System.out.print("K=");

        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            K = sc.nextInt();
        else {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            sc.close();
            return;
        }
        sc.close();

        if (K >= 0 && K <= 9) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 9; ++k) {

                A[k] = k * K;
            }
            for (int k = 0; k <= 4; ++k) {

                B[k] = 10 * (k + 1) * K;

            }
        }
        else if (K < 0 || K > 9) {
            K = 5;
            Random diapazons = new Random();
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; ++c) {
                A[c] = diapazons.nextInt(50);
            }
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; ++c) {
                B[c] = diapazons.nextInt(100 - 50 + 1) + 50;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("A: " + Arrays.toString(A));
        System.out.println("B: " + Arrays.toString(B));

        int count = K;

        while (count > K && count <= A.length) {
            int x = 0;
            x++;
            A[K] = B[x];
            count++;

        }

        System.out.println("A: " + Arrays.toString(A));
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You _need_ quite a lot. But first of all: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your ques is not clear.

Comment: I have no idea how adding the values from B to A produces that result. I also have no idea what K is, and which role it plays. You should start by trying to explain to yourself (and us) what you're supposed to do, in a clear way.

Comment: Next time please post your code in the question and not in an external site.

Comment: perhaps you want to have `A[k] = 5 * K;`

Comment: Please post the original assignment so we can all be clear as to what you need to do.

Comment: I translated the part of the assignment that is within the context of my question and added it to the original thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a **noobie** in stack overflow . 
First of all I suggest you to use ArrayList as they are more flexible once learnt.
It's not a clean or optimised code but,
Try to add the following algorithm into your code .
**I am a noobie trying to be active and learn and participate in stack overflow. This code might have blunder bugs in it. But I hope I helped explain the approach of the alogirthm.**

```
void mergep(ArrayList<Integer> a[], ArrayList<Integer> b[], ArrayList<Integer> c)
{
  int acursor = c;
  int bcursor = 0;
  while(acursor<= b.length())
  {
     int shiftcursor = b.length()-1;
     while(shiftcursor>acursor)
     {
         a[shiftcursor+1] = a[shiftcursor];
         shiftcursor--;//This shifts all the existing entries to the right
     }
     a[acursor] = b[bcursor];
     bcursor++;
     acursor++;
   }
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use ArrayLists in this assignement.
But thank you anyways!

Comment: is it  mentioned specifically to merge the arrays or just print the output as required.

Comment: Merge and then print.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
int count = K;

while (count > K && count <= A.length) {
    int x = 0;
    x++;
    A[K] = B[x];
    count++;
}
```

has a few problems:

- It does nothing because you set `count = K` and then give the condition `count > K`.
- The condition `count <= A.length` will cause a AIOOBE because the last element is at `A.length - 1`.
- You want to start accessing `B` from the beginning, but you increment its value before the first access to it.
- Since you are iterating over `B` as well, you will need a stop condition in the loop to not attempt to access indexes greater than it has.
- You are putting values of `B` into `A`, but at the same time you are losing the ones in `A` because they are overridden. You need to store the value at the right place before you overwrite it.

Once you fix these mistakes you will solve your problem. You can edit your question with your attempt at solving these.

Answer (score 0):

The elements in `A` have to be moved before the elements from `B` can be inserted. Begin by shifting all values from the back of the array to avoid losing any elements. The shift of the elements should look as follows when moving the elements one step to the right:

```
 1. [5, 10, 15]
 2. [5, 10, 15] 15
 3. [5, 10, 10] 15
 4. [5, 5, 10] 15
 5. [2, 5, 10] 15
```

The element 15 will be dropped from the array, but 5 and 10 will still be kept in the array. 5's old location can then be assigned a new value, e.g. 2.

Iterate from the last index of the array and move the elements so that `B`'s elements can fit. But instead of one step as above, move the elements the length of `B`. Stop iterating when index `K` is reached, since no more elements will be inserted or moved. The below java code moves the elements of array `A` and assigns the values from `B`. The first if statement avoids indexing out of bounds. The second if statement checks if the elements from `B` should be inserted into `A`.

```
 int idxA = A.length - 1;
 int idxB = B.length - 1;
 while(idxA >= K){
    if (idxA + B.length < A.length)
        A[idxA + B.length] =  A[idxA];

    if (idxA < B.length + K){
        A[idxA] = B[idxB];
        idxB--;
    }

    idxA--;
 }
```

If you are unsure about how the code works, use pen and paper to write the current state of each array at each step in the code.

Answer (score -2):

I modified the code as per output.

```
    // while (count > K && count <= A.length) {
    // int x = 0;
    // x++;
    // A[K] = B[x];
    // count++;
    //
    // }
```

Change to new code

```
    System.arraycopy(A, K, A, K + B.length, B.length);
    System.arraycopy(B, 0, A, K, B.length);
```

Comment: This conflicts with the asker's instructions.